# Unable to do autocomplete in Excel

Tags: excel, autocomplete

There are data:

[image]

AutoFill need it with this order. I change cell format to:

[image]

then made autocomplete, but the result is the number of filled not by 7 units, and 9 or 10 pieces:

[image]

how to make autocomplete in order to each number were 7 pieces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following in the top cell,

```
'EN-US
=INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/ 7)+1
'RU-RU
=ЦЕЛОЕ((СТРОКА(1:1)-1)/ 7)+1
```

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: in place of 1: 1 is necessary to specify the coordinates of the first number?

Comment: I'm afraid I truly do not understand that question. Did you try it?

Comment: What language is your Office installation? See above for the RU-RU translation.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the formulas:

```
+--------+
| 1      |
| =A1    |
| =A2    |
| =A3    |
| =A4    |
| =A5    |
| =A6    |
| =A7+1  |
| =A8    |
| =A9    |
| =A10   |
| =A11   |
| =A12   |
| =A13   |
| =A14+1 |
| =A15   |
| =A16   |
| =A17   |
| =A18   |
| =A19   |
| =A20   |
| =A21+1 |
| =A22   |
| =A23   |
| =A24   |
| =A25   |
| =A26   |
| =A27   |
| =A28+1 |
| =A29   |
| =A30   |
| =A31   |
| =A32   |
| =A33   |
| =A34   |
| =A35+1 |
| =A36   |
| =A37   |
| =A38   |
| =A39   |
| =A40   |
| =A41   |
+--------+
```

Beginning in cell `A1`, where you put a `1`, in `A2` just `=A1` to take the value of the above cell, to `A7`, and in `A8` you put `=A7+1`. 
This way you get seven `1`'s, seven `2`'s and so on.

Comment: if it is possible to supplement the answer: Make it to the = A14 + 1. And then select the cell from a  = A1 to = A14 + 1 and to keep the lower right corner of promoting mouse down ... If you add this word to your answer, your answer will be a complete answer to this question ...