# Refer to same cell n times then next cell

Tags: excel

So I have a list of persons on sheet1 but then on sheet two i need to refer to a cell 4 times in a row then next cell 4 times, and son on
so on sheet 2 i want this

```
=Shee1(A1)
=Shee1(A1)
=Shee1(A1)
=Shee1(A1)
=Shee1(A2)
=Shee1(A2)
=Shee1(A2)
=Shee1(A2)

if i try to auto complete that it will go like
=Shee1(A1)
=Shee1(A1)
=Shee1(A1)
=Shee1(A1)
=Shee1(A2)
=Shee1(A2)
=Shee1(A2)
=Shee1(A2)
=Sheet1(A9)
```

(because im now 9 cells down from first cell)

Now i could just write all this for 400 cells - but there has to be a better way :)

Comment: Have a look at [Unable to do autocomplete in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192419/unable-to-do-autocomplete-in-excel/35192884#35192884). You will need to use an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to reference **Sheet1!A:A** (not Sheet1(A1)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finaly figured it out - after 4 days for ARGHHH
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$999,INT((ROWS(A$1:A1)-1)/4)+1)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(A:A,FLOOR(((ROW(1:1)-1)/ 4)+1,1))
```

[image]

***If you put formula in `Sheet2` then just refer sheet2 in index array, like:-***

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,FLOOR(((ROW(1:1)-1)/ 4)+1,1))
```